# cleaning nullptr in one-to-many relation that use custom weak pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, one-to-many, handle

I have a one-to-many map class - `MyMap1N<WeakPtr_Parent,WeakPtr_Children>`.
By design, it is supposed to store weak pointers of game-related instance.

Roughly speaking, it is called like :-

```
MyMap1N<WeakPtr<Room>,WeakPtr<RigidBody>> map;
WeakPtr<Room> room=create<Room>();
WeakPtr<RigidBody> body=create<RigidBody>();
map.add(room,body);
MyArray<WeakPtr<RigidBody>> bodys=map.getAllChildren(room);
```

By profiling, I found that `std::unordered_map` is too slow.
Thus, I had to find another way to implement it.

I decided to create an array (instead of `unordered_map`) in `Room`.
To increase speed of query, I also inject the `indexInArray` to store near every instance of `RigidBody` (see the below image).

With this `indexInArray`, it is possible to make operation `add(room,body)` and `remove(room,body)` get `O(1)`, and guarantee that every slot of `Room::bodys` is occupied.

[image]

## Question

A problem arises when some instances of child (`RigidBody`) are deleted.
`MyMap1N` cannot even know it.

[image]

How to clean the `MyMap1N` when some instances of `RigidBody` is deleted?

**Note : (available tools / restriction)**

- In my case, fortunately, cost of checking "whether `WeakPtr<>` is `nullptr`"  is very cheap.
- Every instance has its own unique `int` ID.
  The ID runs separating for each type and the ID's value is low (because I recycle it).
- I use multi-threading.
- **(Edit:clarify)** There are a lot of `MyMap1N<Something,Something>` that scatters around in many `System-like` class.
  Thus, it is very unmaintainable to hardcode like this :-

  ```
  rigidBody->destroy() ===> {     
          SystemA::mapRoomBody::removeParent(rigidBody) ;
          SystemA::mapCatBody::removeParent(rigidBody) ;
          SystemB::mapBodyDog::removeAllChildren(rigidBody) ;
  }  //: Cat and Dog denotes some arbitrary GameObject-type class
  ```

## My poor solution

### Solution 1

I register **every** instances of `MyMap1N` to a central location automatically.

If a RigidBody is deleted, the central system will **callback** to **every** related `MyMap1N`.

(To determine whether a `MyMap1N` is related,
I used some template magic like `MyMap1N::Type_Parent` and `MyMap1N::Type_Children`.)

```
rigidBody->destroy()   
    ===> central->kill(RigidBody*) 
        ===> MyMap1N<WeakPtr<Room>,WeakPtr<RigidBody>>::removeParent(RigidBody*) 
              ... and many other related instances of MyMap1N
```

It works, but very slow.
I believe cache miss is the cause (not sure).

### Solution 2 (my old version)

Whenever a user wants to delete a `RigidBody`, just marks it.
At the end of timestep, do same as workaround 1.
It is faster.  Perhaps, it is because computer love batching. (e.g. less vtable cost)
However, it still uses CPU about 10-20% of the whole game.

### Solution 3 (currently using)

If a `RigidBody` is deleted, don't do anything.
However, when I query `add(room,body)/remove(room,body)/getAllChildren(room)/getParent(body)`, I have to check whether `WeakPtr<>==nullptr`.

It is fast.  There is zero cost at the deleting and every query is also fast.

The disadvantage is that the array `Room::bodys` grows ***forever***
because `Room::Bodys` gradually filled with `X` (`Occupied but the object was deleted`).
My program throws an assert-memory-fail at the 200th time-step.

[image]

### Solution 4

I am considering using Solution 3,
but also creating a new function `MyMap1N::periodicCleanUp` to remove all the `X` i.e. repack it.

The function should be called periodically, perhaps once every 10 timesteps.
 (like a big cleaning day)

I feel it is a hack and highly based on custom tuning (i.e. subjective adjustment).

Comment: Could it be an option to alter the addition method to try to use an empty slot before adding at the end of the array? BTW, you call it array but it should be a vector...

Comment: @Serge Ballesta  Yes, it is possible, but I have to search for it using `O(array-length)`.  Currently, it is just `O(1)`.  BTW, I think `vector` stands for `std::vector`, while `array` is a more general term, thus `array` is a more suitable word, no?

Comment: I see you have getAllChildren method. Do you need to often iterate through all the children? If yes - it's quite easy to perform cleaning during iteration.

Comment: No problem for the *array* term. It was just to notice that in C++ it is very common to encapsulate arrays in `std::vector`. For the main part, if I correctly remember, many tools dealing with slots can can become emply often use a linked list of empty slots to speedup *smart* allocation. But the goal is different: it is to avoid to compact the *array* each time *something* is deleted.

Comment: @Dmitry Gordon Ha ha, I see what you mean.   In most instances of `MyMap1N`, yes, but there is no guarantee. For some instances, I usually iterate it up to 10 times in a time-step (may lead to too often clean-up).  For other instances, I usually iterate once every 3 time-steps (may lead to over-size array).  By the way, it is a useful idea, thank.

Comment: Maybe you can introduce some counter in a parent. Each time one of the child objects is destroyed and when the value of the counter exceeds some value - you can do a clean

Comment: @Dmitry Gordon  I can only imagine that it must be implemented by callback pattern similar as Solution 1.  I don't think it would be fast.   Perhaps, I can apply your idea in global level - count RigidBody deletion - then do a global cleaning for any related instance of `MyMap1N`.  I may need to slow it down by using `mutex` though, because I also do multi-threading (question edited).  Or, I may ignore race condition because approximate value is enough.  Interesting idea, thank.

Comment: Why callback? You can store a weak reference to a parent and just increment atomic value in destructor. You will need to hold the mutex only when you do a cleaning, that's a relatively rare case.

Comment: @Dmitry Gordon  I have a lot of `MyMap1N` that relates to any certain type (e.g. `RigidBody`).    If a `RigidBody` is deleted, how come every `MyMap1N` know the deletion?  I must make `rigidBodyX::destroy(){` to call `relatedMap1->notifyDelete(rigidBodyX)`, `relatedMap2->notifyDelete(rigidBodyX)`, ... `}`.  If I don't want to hardcode, I can't find other ways besides registering every related `MyMap1N`s to listen when `rigidBodyX` is deleted.  Currently, I register callback using type in template i.e. `<WeakPtr_Parent,WeakPtr_Children>` automatically.

Comment: @Dmitry Gordon It may be confusing.  If I don't explain it clearly enough, please ask.

Comment: Yes, I see - one child object can occur in several maps. But anyway - you store index in a parent array, so for each of the maps you initialize index in parent. So you can have vector of references to parent map and initialize it just where you initialize indexInArray. Sorry if I understood something wrong. Possibly a simple example, where all the fields of Room and RigidBody are removed would help in a question description

Comment: @Dmitry Gordon No, you understand everything correctly.  XD.  I can store the reference to parent map too.  What you stated is also a possible solution (I tried it 2 years ago - but it is very slow - it made me very sad).  Unfortunately, based on my feeling after a lot of profiling, any attempt to refer {from a child - to parent map}  whether at the deletion-site or batchly-at-the-end-of-timestep - costs CPU significantly.   ... I am still pondering about the counting your stated ... with some modification, it might be the best way.

Comment: are the IDs numbers? Maybe you could just use the ID as the index - you said you already have ID recycling working. New items would replace deleted items and the array size would be more or less constant. BTW, this is C++ at it's finest - this is not programming, this is memory management :)

Comment: @Krzysztof Skowronek Yes, it is `int` (I will edit question).  Yes, with the ID technique alone, I can guarantee that  `Room::bodys`'s length always less than a certain number e.g. 1000, which is still far from efficient.  :)

Comment: @javaLover you c++ guys are weird with the "efficiency" - if the IDs come up to a 1000, it means that at some point you will have a 1000 RigidBodies. You are making a game, so I think you can assess the max number (or something close to max) of stuff for each level, so that you can preallocate the array. Having 1000 empty pointers isn't that bad if it makes the game faster. Unless you aim to be able to play that game on arduino, I would say it is good enough. That way you essentially substitute the map with an array

Comment: Another idea - in your map, have a set (unordered_set) that contains free indexes. Go back to solution one, but instead of removing the pointer and repacking, just add the index to the set. When adding item to the map/array, grab index from the set (or even make it a stack and pop one) and set the pointer value

Comment: @Krzysztof Skowronek  My example is bad.   A more sensible example is when there are 1000 parents & 1000 children.  Using the MAX-style reserving,  I will have to reserve 1000 arrays that has size=1000 for a map.  It is inefficient. XD .... Your "set/stack"-solution is interesting.  If I understand correctly, I have to add 1 stack per instance of parent, right?   I have never thought about it.      Thank.

Comment: yes, one stack per parent. As for efficiency, it's 16 bytes per weak_ptr - I thought weak_ptr is much smaller. .NET reference is 8 bytes on x64 platforms and can do much more. Still, it's 15MB for 1000 parents with 1000 children - not bad, given that a computer has 8GB of  RAM. Memory efficiency is very relative. Of course, if you diregard 5 topics like that, it will stack, but one? Please :P

Comment: @Krzysztof Skowronek Yes, 15MB is not so much in these days.  I worry about `getAllChildren(room)`.  There would be a lot of cache miss to iterate 1000 (probably empty) children slots. :P

Comment: You said that checking is cheap. Either way, good luck :)

Comment: How about using a custom deleter for your RigidBody instance, that takes care of removing the references from containers (e. g. the map)? See my answer to another post: [C++ container which automatically deletes elements when destructed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813636/c-container-which-automatically-deletes-elements-when-destructed/41596018#41596018)

Comment: @Lorenz Zhao I think it has the same disadvantage as Solution 1.

Comment: @Krzysztof Skowronek  Yes, it is cheap, but even comparing 1000 instances of cheap things (like raw pointers==nullptr) is not so much fun for CPU and memory, when it is avoidable.  IMHO, Solution 2 is a lot cheaper.  I didn't test it yet though.

Answer (score 1):

From what has been gathered from the question and the comments, there appears to be a few viable solutions.

## Solution 1

The first possible solution that others have been pointing out in the comments would be using a free index slot before appending to the array. This would involve each `Room` or object holding an array `RigidBody` to have a list of free indexes, `std::forward_list` or `std::vector` would be good for this. Then, you can add a `RigidBody` by first checking if there an available slot from the list. If there is, you pop off that index from the list, otherwise you append to the array. Removing a `RigidBody` simply involves pushing that freed up index to the list of available slots. Now, this solution would require that each `RigidBody` contains a list of parent and index pairs. That way, when the `RigidBody` is destroyed you simply notify each parent to free up the index the object was using.

#### Advantages

- Could be a bit odd to implement.
- Adding and removing is `O(1)`.
- Iteration speed is generally good.

#### Disadvantages

- Uses a decent amount of memory.
- The array will be growing.
- Have to use a unique key per parent.

## Solution 2

There is also another similar type of solution that was discussed in the comments. However, instead of a `RigidBody` having multiple indexes for each parents, it has one unique ID that acts as an index. This unique ID should have a known range of minimum and maximum values. Then, each parent would allocate enough space to house the maximum amount of IDs and RigidBodies. The destruction and removal of a RigidBody is simple since you have to simply pass at ID/index to each registered parent. In addition, you could use a list to keep track of free ID's.

#### Advantages

- Array will not be growing during runtime.
- Adding and removing is `O(1)`.
- Less keys and indexes.
- Same key/index for all parents.
- Great if the array is going to be mostly filled.

#### Disadvantages

- Uses a lot of memory.
- Iteration will be inefficient if the array is mostly empty.

## Solution 3

The periodic cleanup idea you suggested could work. However, it is likely that cleaning up all of the arrays in one-go could cost a lot of time. Hence, a possible adjustment would be to partially clear the array at the end of every timestep. That adjustment would require you having to store an index of where you last left off. To which, you would use that index to continue clearing sections of the array. Once the array has been fully cleared you can reset that index to 0 and start over. This solution and adjustment would only work if the rate you are removing bodies is usually greater than the rate of adding bodies.

#### Advantages

- Easy to implement.
- Easy to tune and adjust.

#### Disadvantages

- Could fail depending on the rate of items being added and removed.
- Could use more memory than necessary.

## Solution 4

Another solution would involve using the address or ID of the rigid body to 'hash' or it into an array of vectors. This array of vectors could be accomplished by using a prime number to act as the size of the array. Then, we can use the RigidBodies ID or address and modulo that with the size of the array to place it into a vector. This makes erasing faster than a normal vector. In addition, it uses less memory than a massive static array of slots. Iterating over this structure would involve iterating over each bucket/vector. Or you can create a custom iterator that does this for you.

#### Basic Implementation of Structure

```
namespace {
    template<typename Int>
    constexpr bool isPrime(Int num, Int test = 2) {
        return (test * test > num ? true : (num % test == 0 ? false : isPrime(num, test + 1)));
    }
    //Buckets must be a size
    template<typename data_t, std::size_t PRIME_SIZE, typename = typename std::enable_if<isPrime(PRIME_SIZE)>::type>
    class BucketVector
    {
    public:
        constexpr static auto SIZE = PRIME_SIZE;
        template<bool is_const>
        using BucketIteratorBase = typename  std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, typename std::conditional<is_const, const data_t, data_t>::type>;
        using uint_t = std::uintptr_t;
        using BucketType = std::vector<data_t>;
        template<bool is_const>
        class BucketIterator : public BucketIteratorBase<is_const> {
        public:
            using Base = BucketIteratorBase<is_const>;
            using BucketOwner = BucketVector<data_t, PRIME_SIZE>;
            using typename Base::pointer;
            using typename Base::reference;
            using typename Base::value_type;
            friend class BucketIterator<!is_const>;
            std::size_t m_bucket;
            pointer m_value;
            BucketOwner* m_owner;
        public:
            BucketIterator(std::size_t bucket, pointer value, BucketOwner* owner)
                : m_bucket(bucket),
                m_value(value),
                m_owner(owner) {
                //validateIterator();
            }
            ~BucketIterator() {
            }
            template<bool value, typename = typename std::enable_if<!value || (value == is_const)>::type>
            BucketIterator(const BucketIterator<value>& iterator)
                : m_bucket(iterator.m_bucket),
                m_value(iterator.m_value),
                m_owner(iterator.m_owner) {
            }
            template<bool value, typename = typename std::enable_if<!value || (value == is_const)>::type>
            BucketIterator(BucketIterator<value>&& iterator)
                : m_bucket(std::move(iterator.m_bucket)),
                m_value(std::move(iterator.m_value)),
                m_owner(std::move(iterator.m_owner)) {
            }
            template<bool value, typename = typename std::enable_if<!value || (value == is_const)>::type>
            BucketIterator& operator=(BucketIterator<value>&& iterator) {
                m_bucket = std::move(iterator.m_bucket);
                m_value = std::move(iterator.m_value);
                m_owner = std::move(iterator.m_owner);
                return *this;
            }
            template<bool value, typename = typename std::enable_if<!value || (value == is_const)>::type>
            BucketIterator& operator=(const BucketIterator<value>& iterator) {
                m_bucket = iterator.m_bucket;
                m_value = iterator.m_value;
                m_owner = iterator.m_owner;
                return *this;
            }
            BucketIterator& operator++() {
                ++m_value;
                forwardValidate();
                return *this;
            }
            BucketIterator operator++(int) {
                BucketIterator copy(*this);
                ++(*this);
                return copy;
            }
            BucketIterator& operator--() {
                backwardValidate();
                --m_value;
                return *this;
            }
            BucketIterator operator--(int) {
                BucketIterator copy(*this);
                --(*this);
                return copy;
            }
            reference operator*() const {
                return *m_value;
            }
            pointer operator->() const {
                return m_value;
            }
            template<bool value>
            bool operator==(const BucketIterator<value>& iterator) const {
                return m_bucket == iterator.m_bucket && m_owner == iterator.m_owner && m_value == iterator.m_value;
            }
            template<bool value>
            bool operator!=(const BucketIterator<value>& iterator) const {
                return !(this->operator==(iterator));
            }
            BucketOwner* getSystem() const {
                return m_owner;
            }
            inline void backwardValidate() {
                while (m_value == m_owner->m_buckets[m_bucket].data() && m_bucket != 0) {
                    --m_bucket;
                    m_value = m_owner->m_buckets[m_bucket].data() + m_owner->m_buckets[m_bucket].size();
                }
            }
            inline void forwardValidate() {
                while (m_value == (m_owner->m_buckets[m_bucket].data() + m_owner->m_buckets[m_bucket].size()) && m_bucket != SIZE - 1) {
                    m_value = m_owner->m_buckets[++m_bucket].data();
                }
            }
        };
        using iterator = BucketIterator<false>;
        using const_iterator = BucketIterator<true>;
        friend class BucketIterator<false>;
        friend class BucketIterator<true>;
    private:
        std::array<BucketType, SIZE> m_buckets;
        std::size_t m_size;
    public:
        BucketVector()
            : m_size(0) {
        }
        ~BucketVector() {
        }
        BucketVector(const BucketVector&) = default;
        BucketVector(BucketVector&&) = default;
        BucketVector& operator=(const BucketVector&) = default;
        BucketVector& operator=(BucketVector&&) = default;
        data_t& operator[](std::size_t index) {
            const auto bucketIndex = findBucketIndex(index);
            return m_buckets[bucketIndex.first][bucketIndex.second];
        }
        const data_t& operator[](std::size_t index) const {
            return static_cast<BucketVector*>(this)->operator[](index);
        }
        data_t& at(std::size_t index) {
            if (index >= m_size) {
                throw std::out_of_range("BucketVector::at index out of range");
            }
            return this->operator[](index);
        }
        const data_t& at(std::size_t index) const {
            return static_cast<BucketVector*>(this)->at(index);
        }
        void erase(const_iterator iter) {
            auto& bucket = m_buckets[iter.m_bucket];
            std::size_t index = iter.m_value - bucket.data();
            bucket[index] = bucket.back();
            bucket.pop_back();
            --m_size;
        }
        void push_back(uint_t id, const data_t& data) {
            const auto slot = get_slot(id);
            m_buckets[slot].push_back(data);
            ++m_size;
        }
        void push_back(uint_t id, data_t&& data) {
            const auto slot = get_slot(id);
            m_buckets[slot].push_back(std::move(data));
            ++m_size;
        }
        template<typename... args>
        void emplace_back(uint_t id, args&&... parameters) {
            const auto slot = get_slot(id);
            m_buckets[slot].emplace_back(std::forward<args>(parameters)...);
            ++m_size;
        }

        void pop_back(uint_t index) {
            const auto slot = get_slot(index);
            m_buckets[slot].pop_back();
            --m_size;
        }
        void pop_front(uint_t index) {
            const auto slot = get_slot(index);
            m_buckets[slot].pop_front();
            --m_size;
        }
        void reserve(std::size_t size) {
            const std::size_t slotSize = size / SIZE + 1;
            for (auto& bucket : m_buckets) {
                bucket.reserve(slotSize);
            }
        }
        void clear() {
            for (auto& bucket : m_buckets) {
                bucket.clear();
            }
        }
        bool empty() const {
            return m_size != 0;
        }
        std::size_t size() const {
            return m_size;
        }
        iterator find(uint_t index, const data_t& value) {
            const std::size_t slot = get_slot(index);
            auto& bucket = m_buckets[slot];
            for (auto it = bucket.begin(), end = bucket.end(); it != end; ++it) {
                if (*it == value) {
                    return { slot, &(*it), this };
                }
            }
            return end();
        }
        template<typename fn_t>
        iterator find(uint_t index, const fn_t& fn) {
            const std::size_t slot = get_slot(index);
            auto& bucket = m_buckets[slot];
            for (auto it = bucket.begin(), end = bucket.end(); it != end; ++it) {
                if (fn(*it)) {
                    return { slot, &(*it), this };
                }
            }
            return end();
        }
        const_iterator find(uint_t index, const data_t& value) const {
            return cfind(index, value);
        }
        const_iterator cfind(uint_t index, const data_t& value) const {
            return static_cast<BucketVector*>(this)->find(index, value);
        }
        iterator begin(uint_t index = 0) {
            auto bucketIndex = findBucketIndex(index);
            iterator it{ bucketIndex.first, m_buckets[bucketIndex.first].data() + bucketIndex.second, this };
            it.forwardValidate();
            return it;
        }
        iterator end(uint_t index = 0) {
            iterator it{ SIZE - 1, m_buckets.back().data() + m_buckets.back().size(), this };
            return it;
        }
        const_iterator begin(uint_t index = 0) const {
            auto bucketIndex = findBucketIndex(index);
            const_iterator it{ bucketIndex.first, m_buckets[bucketIndex.first].data() + bucketIndex.second, this };
            it.forwardValidate();
            return it;
        }
        const_iterator end(uint_t index = 0) const {
            const_iterator it{ SIZE - 1, m_buckets.back().data() + m_buckets.back().size(), this };
            return it;
        }
        std::size_t get_slot(uint_t id) {
            return id % SIZE;
        }
    private:
        inline std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> findBucketIndex(std::size_t index) {
            std::size_t bucket = 0;
            std::size_t count = 0;
            while (index >= m_buckets[bucket].size() + count) {
                count += m_buckets[bucket].size();
                ++bucket;
            }
            return { bucket, index - count };
        }
    };
}
```

#### Advantages

- Appending is `O(1)`.
- Use's less memory than Solution 1 and 2.
- Can be used to quickly find out if a `RigidBody` belongs to a parent.
- Erasing is fast for the size of vector you are going to use.
- Iteration is faster than Solution's 1 and 2 if the array is more than 50% empty.

#### Disadvantages

- Erasing is fast but not as fast as Solution's 1 and 2.
- Vectors will grow.
- Iteration is slower than Solution's 1 and 2 if the array is more than 50% full.

## Basic Benchmark Program

You can use this program to test various inputs such as size and amount of values to remove to see the performance.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <iomanip>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>


template<typename mclock_t = typename std::conditional<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady, std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, std::chrono::steady_clock>::type>
class Benchmarker {
public:
    using ClockType = mclock_t;
    using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<ClockType>;
private:
    TimePoint m_start;
    TimePoint m_end;
    bool m_running;
public:
    Benchmarker(bool run = false) {
        m_running = run;

        if (m_running) {
            start();
        }
    }

    Benchmarker& start() {
        m_start = ClockType::now();
        m_running = true;

        return *this;
    }

    Benchmarker& stop() {
        m_end = ClockType::now();
        m_running = false;

        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T = std::chrono::microseconds>
    Benchmarker& printDuration(std::ostream& out) {
        out << std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(m_end - m_start).count();

        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T = std::chrono::microseconds>
    long long getDurationCount() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(m_end - m_start).count();
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Benchmarker& benchmarker) {
        out << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(benchmarker.m_end - benchmarker.m_start).count();

        return out;
    }

    TimePoint getDuration() {
        return m_end - m_start;
    }

    TimePoint getStartTime() {
        return m_start;
    }

    TimePoint getEndTime() {
        return m_end;
    }

    bool isRunning() {
        return m_running;
    }
};

namespace {
    template<typename Int>
    constexpr bool isPrime(Int num, Int test = 2) {
        return (test * test > num ? true : (num % test == 0 ? false : isPrime(num, test + 1)));
    }
    //Buckets must be a size
    template<typename data_t, std::size_t PRIME_SIZE, typename = typename std::enable_if<isPrime(PRIME_SIZE)>::type>
    class BucketVector
    {
    public:
        constexpr static auto SIZE = PRIME_SIZE;
        template<bool is_const>
        using BucketIteratorBase = typename  std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, typename std::conditional<is_const, const data_t, data_t>::type>;
        using uint_t = std::uintptr_t;
        using BucketType = std::vector<data_t>;
        template<bool is_const>
        class BucketIterator : public BucketIteratorBase<is_const> {
        public:
            using Base = BucketIteratorBase<is_const>;
            using BucketOwner = BucketVector<data_t, PRIME_SIZE>;
            using typename Base::pointer;
            using typename Base::reference;
            using typename Base::value_type;
            friend class BucketIterator<!is_const>;
            std::size_t m_bucket;
            pointer m_value;
            BucketOwner* m_owner;
        public:
            BucketIterator(std::size_t bucket, pointer value, BucketOwner* owner)
                : m_bucket(bucket),
                m_value(value),
                m_owner(owner) {
                //validateIterator();
            }
            ~BucketIterator() {
            }
            template<bool value, typename = typename std::enable_if<!value || (value == is_const)>::type>
            BucketIterator(const BucketIterator<value>& iterator)
                : m_bucket(iterator.m_bucket),
                m_value(iterator.m_value),
                m_owner(iterator.m_owner) {
            }
            template<bool value, typename = typename std::enable_if<!value || (value == is_const)>::type>
            BucketIterator(BucketIterator<value>&& iterator)
                : m_bucket(std::move(iterator.m_bucket)),
                m_value(std::move(iterator.m_value)),
                m_owner(std::move(iterator.m_owner)) {
            }
            template<bool value, typename = typename std::enable_if<!value || (value == is_const)>::type>
            BucketIterator& operator=(BucketIterator<value>&& iterator) {
                m_bucket = std::move(iterator.m_bucket);
                m_value = std::move(iterator.m_value);
                m_owner = std::move(iterator.m_owner);
                return *this;
            }
            template<bool value, typename = typename std::enable_if<!value || (value == is_const)>::type>
            BucketIterator& operator=(const BucketIterator<value>& iterator) {
                m_bucket = iterator.m_bucket;
                m_value = iterator.m_value;
                m_owner = iterator.m_owner;
                return *this;
            }
            BucketIterator& operator++() {
                ++m_value;
                forwardValidate();
                return *this;
            }
            BucketIterator operator++(int) {
                BucketIterator copy(*this);
                ++(*this);
                return copy;
            }
            BucketIterator& operator--() {
                backwardValidate();
                --m_value;
                return *this;
            }
            BucketIterator operator--(int) {
                BucketIterator copy(*this);
                --(*this);
                return copy;
            }
            reference operator*() const {
                return *m_value;
            }
            pointer operator->() const {
                return m_value;
            }
            template<bool value>
            bool operator==(const BucketIterator<value>& iterator) const {
                return m_bucket == iterator.m_bucket && m_owner == iterator.m_owner && m_value == iterator.m_value;
            }
            template<bool value>
            bool operator!=(const BucketIterator<value>& iterator) const {
                return !(this->operator==(iterator));
            }
            BucketOwner* getSystem() const {
                return m_owner;
            }
            inline void backwardValidate() {
                while (m_value == m_owner->m_buckets[m_bucket].data() && m_bucket != 0) {
                    --m_bucket;
                    m_value = m_owner->m_buckets[m_bucket].data() + m_owner->m_buckets[m_bucket].size();
                }
            }
            inline void forwardValidate() {
                while (m_value == (m_owner->m_buckets[m_bucket].data() + m_owner->m_buckets[m_bucket].size()) && m_bucket != SIZE - 1) {
                    m_value = m_owner->m_buckets[++m_bucket].data();
                }
            }
        };
        using iterator = BucketIterator<false>;
        using const_iterator = BucketIterator<true>;
        friend class BucketIterator<false>;
        friend class BucketIterator<true>;
    private:
        std::array<BucketType, SIZE> m_buckets;
        std::size_t m_size;
    public:
        BucketVector()
            : m_size(0) {
        }
        ~BucketVector() {
        }
        BucketVector(const BucketVector&) = default;
        BucketVector(BucketVector&&) = default;
        BucketVector& operator=(const BucketVector&) = default;
        BucketVector& operator=(BucketVector&&) = default;
        data_t& operator[](std::size_t index) {
            const auto bucketIndex = findBucketIndex(index);
            return m_buckets[bucketIndex.first][bucketIndex.second];
        }
        const data_t& operator[](std::size_t index) const {
            return static_cast<BucketVector*>(this)->operator[](index);
        }
        data_t& at(std::size_t index) {
            if (index >= m_size) {
                throw std::out_of_range("BucketVector::at index out of range");
            }
            return this->operator[](index);
        }
        const data_t& at(std::size_t index) const {
            return static_cast<BucketVector*>(this)->at(index);
        }
        void erase(const_iterator iter) {
            auto& bucket = m_buckets[iter.m_bucket];
            std::size_t index = iter.m_value - bucket.data();
            bucket[index] = bucket.back();
            bucket.pop_back();
            --m_size;
        }
        void push_back(uint_t id, const data_t& data) {
            const auto slot = get_slot(id);
            m_buckets[slot].push_back(data);
            ++m_size;
        }
        void push_back(uint_t id, data_t&& data) {
            const auto slot = get_slot(id);
            m_buckets[slot].push_back(std::move(data));
            ++m_size;
        }
        template<typename... args>
        void emplace_back(uint_t id, args&&... parameters) {
            const auto slot = get_slot(id);
            m_buckets[slot].emplace_back(std::forward<args>(parameters)...);
            ++m_size;
        }

        void pop_back(uint_t index) {
            const auto slot = get_slot(index);
            m_buckets[slot].pop_back();
            --m_size;
        }
        void pop_front(uint_t index) {
            const auto slot = get_slot(index);
            m_buckets[slot].pop_front();
            --m_size;
        }
        void reserve(std::size_t size) {
            const std::size_t slotSize = size / SIZE + 1;
            for (auto& bucket : m_buckets) {
                bucket.reserve(slotSize);
            }
        }
        void clear() {
            for (auto& bucket : m_buckets) {
                bucket.clear();
            }
        }
        bool empty() const {
            return m_size != 0;
        }
        std::size_t size() const {
            return m_size;
        }
        iterator find(uint_t index, const data_t& value) {
            const std::size_t slot = get_slot(index);
            auto& bucket = m_buckets[slot];
            for (auto it = bucket.begin(), end = bucket.end(); it != end; ++it) {
                if (*it == value) {
                    return { slot, &(*it), this };
                }
            }
            return end();
        }
        template<typename fn_t>
        iterator find(uint_t index, const fn_t& fn) {
            const std::size_t slot = get_slot(index);
            auto& bucket = m_buckets[slot];
            for (auto it = bucket.begin(), end = bucket.end(); it != end; ++it) {
                if (fn(*it)) {
                    return { slot, &(*it), this };
                }
            }
            return end();
        }
        const_iterator find(uint_t index, const data_t& value) const {
            return cfind(index, value);
        }
        const_iterator cfind(uint_t index, const data_t& value) const {
            return static_cast<BucketVector*>(this)->find(index, value);
        }
        iterator begin(uint_t index = 0) {
            auto bucketIndex = findBucketIndex(index);
            iterator it{ bucketIndex.first, m_buckets[bucketIndex.first].data() + bucketIndex.second, this };
            it.forwardValidate();
            return it;
        }
        iterator end(uint_t index = 0) {
            iterator it{ SIZE - 1, m_buckets.back().data() + m_buckets.back().size(), this };
            return it;
        }
        const_iterator begin(uint_t index = 0) const {
            auto bucketIndex = findBucketIndex(index);
            const_iterator it{ bucketIndex.first, m_buckets[bucketIndex.first].data() + bucketIndex.second, this };
            it.forwardValidate();
            return it;
        }
        const_iterator end(uint_t index = 0) const {
            const_iterator it{ SIZE - 1, m_buckets.back().data() + m_buckets.back().size(), this };
            return it;
        }
        std::size_t get_slot(uint_t id) {
            return id % SIZE;
        }
    private:
        inline std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> findBucketIndex(std::size_t index) {
            std::size_t bucket = 0;
            std::size_t count = 0;
            while (index >= m_buckets[bucket].size() + count) {
                count += m_buckets[bucket].size();
                ++bucket;
            }
            return { bucket, index - count };
        }
    };
}

constexpr std::size_t SIZE = 1'000;
constexpr std::size_t INDEXES = 400;
constexpr std::size_t SPACING = 26;

void vectorFindErase(std::vector<int>& values, int value) {
    const auto end = values.end();
    for (auto it = values.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
        if (*it == value) {
            values.erase(it);
            break;
        }
    }
}
void vectorEraseSorted(std::vector<int>& values, int value) {
    auto it = std::lower_bound(values.begin(), values.end(), value);
    if (it != values.end() && !(value < *it)) {
        values.erase(it);
    }
}

void setErase(std::unordered_set<int>& values, int value) {
    values.erase(value);
}
int main() {
    std::mt19937 rng;
    rng.seed(std::random_device()());


    std::vector<int> values(SIZE);
    std::generate_n(values.begin(), SIZE, []() {
        static int index = 0;
        return index++;
    });
    auto sorted = values;
    auto preallocate = values;
    auto vnf = values;

    std::random_shuffle(vnf.begin(), vnf.end(), [&](auto i) {
        return rng() % i;
    });
    std::vector<int> indexes(INDEXES);
    std::generate(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [&]() {
        return rng() % SIZE;
    });

    //APPEND VALUES TO BUCKET VECTOR, USE VALUE AS IT'S OWN KEY
    BucketVector<int, 23> bucket;
    for (auto& value : values) {
        bucket.push_back(value, value);
    }



    Benchmarker<> bench(true);

    //NAIVE FIND AND ERASE
    for (auto& index : indexes) {
        vectorFindErase(vnf, index);
    }
    std::cout << std::left;
    std::cout << std::setw(SPACING) << "Naive Find and Erase: " << bench.stop() << '\n';

    //SORTED ERASE
    bench.start();
    for (auto& index : indexes) {
        vectorEraseSorted(sorted, index);
    }
    std::cout << std::setw(SPACING) << "Sorted erase: " << bench.stop() << '\n';

    //PRELLOCATED ERASE
    bench.start();
    for (auto& index : indexes) {
        preallocate[index] = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    }
    std::cout << std::setw(SPACING) << "Prellocated erase: " << bench.stop() << '\n';

    //BUCKETVECTOR ERASE
    bench.start();
    for (auto& index : indexes) {
        auto it = bucket.find(index, index);
        if (it == bucket.end()) {
            continue;
        }
        bucket.erase(it);
    }

    std::cout << std::setw(SPACING) << "BucketVector erase: " << bench.stop() << '\n';

    //BUCKET SUM/ITERATE
    bench.start();
    long long bucketSum = 0;
    for (std::size_t index = 0; index != 10'000; ++index) {
        for (auto& val : bucket) {
            bucketSum += val;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::setw(SPACING) << "Bucket Sum/Iterate: " << bench.stop() << ' ' << bucketSum << '\n';


    //PREALLOCATE SUM/ITERATE
    bench.start();
    long long vfsum = 0;
    for (std::size_t index = 0; index != 10'000; ++index) {
        for (auto& val : preallocate) {
            if (val != std::numeric_limits<int>::min()) {
                vfsum += val;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::setw(SPACING) << "Preallocate sum/Iterate: " << bench.stop() << ' ' << vfsum << '\n';
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, I found that the BucketVector was slightly faster to iterate over than a preallocated array when the preallocated array was 50% or more empty with a size of 1000.

Comment: By the way, I like the enhancement in your Solution 3 on my Solution 4.  Thank +1

Comment: Just to check my understanding ; your Solution 1 has the same disadvantage of my Solution 1-2, and your Solution 4 has the same disadvantage as `std::unordered_set` (but with cheaper hash function).  Correct?

Comment: Yeah, you are right that it does involve the same disadvantage as your Solution 1-2. However, the act of removing a RigidBody from a single parent is cheap with that form of a data structure. A question, how many different parents can a RigidBody have? The fourth solution essentially involves a niche structure that's a performance hybrid between `std::unordered_set` and `std::vector` that could be useful.