# c++ when creating new object: iterator not incrementable

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I am dealing with a task to create a troop of bunnies where they can multiply at each round. So I define a class of `Bunny` (individual), and then define a class of `Troop` with a vector point to different bunnies.
My problem is, every time I use `new` to create an object Bunny in a loop, it will come out an error says:

*"Debug assertion failed!!...vector iterator not incrementable..."*

Here is a sample of my code:

```
class Bunny {
private:
    string sex;
    string color;
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    string getname() { return name;};
    Bunny(); // constructor
};

class Troop {
private:
    vector<Bunny *> bunpointer;
    vector<Bunny *>::iterator it;
public:
    void newbunny();
    void multiply();
};

void Troop::newbunny() {
    Bunny * bun;  // pointer to the Bunny class
    bun = new Bunny;
    cout << "Bunny " << bun->getname() << " is born! \n";
    bunpointer.push_back(bun);
}

void Troop::multiply() {
    it = bunpointer.begin();
    while(it!=bunpointer.end()) {
        cout << (*it)->getname() << " gave a birth. ";
        newbunny();
        ++it;
    }
    it = bunpointer.begin();
}
```

So if I create 5 bunnies at the beginning, and call function `Troop::multiply`, there should be 10 bunnies. An interesting observation is, the error will occur after 2 bunnies being born.

I think the problem may lie in the use of `new` to create new objects in a iterator loop. The `new` may somehow interrupt the iterator pointer `*it`. But I am not sure if this is the case, and if it really is, how to deal with this.

modified: so it is actually a problem of using `push_back()`, which will probably invalidate the `iterator`!!

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Why do you need to use `new` at all in this program?  Why not just a `vector<Bunny>`?

Comment: `psuh_back` invalidates iterators.

Comment: hi @chris yes I think it is the `push_back` problem. And @PaulMcKenzie, honestly, I don't really know, since I am still trying to learn C++ and all I did is imitating people's program...Could you help explain what is the difference between the two? In my case, my `Troop` need to keep multiplying.

Comment: @CSLearner - See my answer for an adjustment to your code and other comments on the issue you're seeing with push_back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Unless you have a reason to, your code does not need to use `new` at all.  The code becomes easier, and no chance of memory leaks.  Also, I don't see the need for an iterator member in the Troop class, unless you can justify the reason for it.

2) As to your immediate problem, just use a non-iterator reliant loop.  In other words, a simple loop that goes from 0 to the number of current bunnies, less 1.

Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>
//...
class Troop {
   private:
       std::vector<Bunny> bunpointer;
   public:
       void newbunny();
       void multiply();
};

void Troop::newbunny() {
   bunpointer.push_back(Bunny());
}

void Troop::multiply() {
    size_t siz = bunpoiner.size(); 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < siz; ++i ) {  
       newbunny();
       cout << (*it)->getname() << " gave a birth. ";
    }
}
```

The newbunny() function simply creates a Bunny() using a default constructor and adds the item to the vector.

If you want to use a container that doesn't invalidate iterators when inserting items, then you can use a `std::list` as opposed to a `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you sir! That really helps. And I will take your suggestion on using `vector::erase()` :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to modify the `std::vector` while iterating over it. This is generally not a good idea, for a variety of reasons.

In particular, when you call `newbunny()` inside the iterator's loop, it is possible that the iterator you used to hold will be invalidated, because the vector may be resized during the `push_back`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624803/does-resizing-a-vector-invalidate-iterators) for details.

Comment: Thank you!! I think it is the `push_back` problem. And could you suggest any solution to this? Using `vector::reserve()` will probably not going to work since my `Troop` will keep multiplying and the required troop size will be unknown.

Comment: @CSLearner, I think the other answers are fairly clear about how to fix it. :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, the `push_back()` is your culprit, not the `new`.

One way to palliate would be this:

```
size_t const max(bunpointer.size());
for(size_t i(0); i < max; ++i)
{
    cout << bunpointer[i]->getname() << " gave a birth. ";
    newbunny();
}
```

This works because you are only adding new bunnies at the end of your existing vector. These new bunnies are not taken in account by the loop (max doesn't change because you call newbunny()...) and the `[i]` access makes use of the vector in its current state.

That loop would not work if you were deleting items...

As a side note: the name "bunpointer" is not very clear... it's not a pointer, it's a vector of pointers.

Comment: Yes I think this will work! Thank you!!
Unfortunately I will need to delete some items in the future because the bunnies need to die when they get old in the program....but I think your way of using `[i]` rather than `iterator` is pretty smart and I will use that before I handle the `delete` issue!

Comment: @CSLearner - When you do get a chance to do the delete, *do not use a loop to do the deletion*.  Learn the vector::erase()/remove_if() idiom.  If you don't delete that way, I can guarantee you that you will post another question on SO as to why you're program is crashing :)