# How can I point to the vector elements?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

a) Is it safe to point to address of a vector element ?

```
unsigned int* ptr;
std::vector<unsigned int> vec;
vec.resize(10);
vec[0] = 10;
ptr = &vec[0];
```

It seems to me, that as long as I dont change the size of the preallocated vector, the address of &vec[0] does not change. My question is, if it is safe to point to an vector element as long as it is preallocated.

b) If I don't preallocate the size of vec, the address of &vec[0] seems to change . If I push additional values to the vector via vec.push_back(). 
I would like to have a vector of pointers that points to an index vector.

```
std::vector<unsigned int*> ptr_vec(10,0);
std::vector<unsigned int> index_vec;
index_vec.push_back(0);
ptr_vec[0] = &index_vector[0];
ptr_vec[1] = ptr_vec[0];
index_vec.push_back(1); // at this point the adress of &index_vec[0] changes. thats my problem
```

Comment: The behavior you described is true. I see no question here.

Comment: my question is, if it is safe to point to an vector element as long as it is preallocated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to respond to your actual question:

> my question is, if it is safe to point to an vector element as long as it is preallocate

Yes, it is. As long as you pre-allocate its contents and you do not change its size in any way.

[Read the documentation of `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for a list of methods that make this kind of pointer manipulation unsafe. (Search for the methods that are said to **"invalidate pointers".**)

Also, see [this related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624803/does-resizing-a-vector-invalidate-iterators), which is about iterator invalidation, a similar concept.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like as `index_vec` vector is not re-sized before, adding the second item '1' is causing STL to allocate more memory and thus moving the original buffer somewhere else.

try to re-size the `index_vec` vector to preserve the buffer.

use `index_vec.resize(10);` for example to reserve 10 places worth of memory.

**EDIT**
and to your question - "safe" depends on the usage... it is doable, but might very very un-safe to point to an STL vector internal buffer.

if the vector is preallocated, (using `resize`) the items' address is maintained. but if you push 1 additional item to the vector, STL might change the memory location (that is what nice about STL... memory management is owned by the library, and not us ;-) )

Comment: thanks for your reply. my question would be, if it is safe to point to an vector element, as long as i allocate the memory

Comment: @ArthurSpooner - see my edit, just replied to your `safe` question