# How to clear a vector but keeping its capacity?

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to fix some code that uses vectors a lot and there are some loops that look like this:

```
for (int t=0;t<T;t++){    
    std::vector<double> vect;
    for (int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        double value;
        vect.push_back(value);
    }
    /*....*/
}
```

I know more or less how to improve this by reusing the same vector for the outer iterations, but while doing this I found that when calling `std::vector::clear` ["the vector capacity is not guaranteed to change"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/), while I was actually hoping that the capacity would be guaranteed to not change. Maybe I am just misunderstanding what is written on cplusplus.com. However, my question is:

**How can I clear a vector without changing its capacity?**

Should I call `reserve` after `clear` to make sure the capacity will be the same?

**PS:** just to be clear, I want to rewrite above code to

```
std::vector<double> vect;
vect.reserve(MAX);
for (int t=0;t<T;t++){    
    for (int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        double value;
        vect.push_back(value);
    }
    /*....*/
    vect.clear();
}
```

ie. I still want to fill it via `push_back` and I am worried about the `clear()` changing the capacity of the vector.

Comment: There's related discussion here. The consensus seems to be that resizing a vector SMALLER must not affecte the capacity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624803/does-resizing-a-vector-invalidate-iterators

Comment: A better answer was in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18467916

Answer (score 17):

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) said explicitly that the capacity of the vector is unchanged.

from cppreference (bold emphases it is own me):

> ```
> void clear();
> ```
>
> Removes all elements from the container. Invalidates any references,
>   pointers, or iterators referring to contained elements. May invalidate
>   any past-the-end iterators.
>   **Leaves the capacity() of the vector unchanged.**

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Dmitry Kuznetsov in the comment, the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) does not mention the capacity:

> *expression:* `a.clear()`
>
> *return type:* `void`
>   *Assertion/note pre-/post-condition:* Destroys all elements in a. Invalidates all references, pointers, and iterators referring to the
>   elements of a and may invalidate the past-the-end iterator.
>
> *post:* a.empty() returns true.
>
> *Complexity:* Linear.

Comment: hm in that case it would be interesting what the standard says because cplusplus states that this is not guaranteed.

Comment: it could well be that it is just a typo on cplusplus and instead of "not guaranteed to change" they actually meant "guaranteed not to change"

Comment: if in doubt refer to the standard. Anyways I would not care about what is written on cplusplus.

Comment: I think this is correct. also, `resize(0)` is guaranteed not to modify capacity, according to cppreference.com

Comment: so then at least with respect to `clear`, cplusplus is correct and cppreference is not, right?

Comment: yeap, it appears to be so (at least in this case).

Comment: The standard says it elsewhere

Comment: @Cubbi, do you want to point it out where in the standard? It is a long document.

Comment: I linked the discussion in the comment to the original question above

Comment: @Cubbi thanks, my bad, I haven't noticed it

Answer (score 3):

Yes, call `reserve()` after `clear()`. In the worst case, you'll have a single deallocation/allocation taking place, which would have negligible impact in case of a vector of PODs.

Comment: Doesn't matter that it's PODs. There's no object construction taking place when you call `clear()`

Answer (score 2):

You can store value returned from `capacity()` and use `reserve()` method.

It's not guaranteed to give you the exact same [capacity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve):

> Increase the capacity of the container to a value that's greater or
>   equal to new_cap. If new_cap is greater than the current capacity(),
>   new storage is allocated, otherwise the method does nothing.

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    size_t cap = vec.capacity(); 
    vec.clear();
    vec.reserve(cap);

    cout << "vec capacity: " << vec.capacity() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: where did you take the quote? In particular I am interested whether it is really guaranteed to do nothing in case the requested capacity is smaller than the current capacity. Not that it would matter so much, but sometimes details do matter

Comment: ah thanks, actually I was a bit confused, because in my quote I mixed up cppreference with cplusplus...

Answer (score -1):

Another way would be to do a do a swap trick...

```
std::vector<double> vect = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}
{
    std::vector<double> swapVector;
    swapVector.reserve(vect.capacity());
    vect.swap(swapVector); // swapVector now has the elements of vect
                           // vect has only reserved elements
} // swapVector will be destroyed (including the elements that was in vect)
std::cout << vect.capacity();
```

Comment: "vect will be cleared when it goes out of scope" ?? I dont understand

Comment: @tobi303 swapVector is created on the stack and has been swapped with the elements in vect. As soon as the function goes out of scope swapVector will be destroyed and it's elements... let me edit my answer

Comment: I see plenty of downside and no advantages to this approach. You're forcing a deallocation and reallocation (although in the other order), whichg is exactly what the OP wants to avoid,

Comment: @Roddy yeah I guess you're right. The only benefit would be (if that would be needed) is that vect is "emptied" before the elements are deallocated...

Answer (score -2):

Calling `clear` will deallocate (not necessarily, but depending on the implementation), then calling `resize` will result in a costly reallocation. The obvious answer would be to just iterate though the vector and to set the results to `0 / NULL`:

```
for(double& d : vect)
{
    d = 0;
    //d = NULL, depending on datatype
}
```

This will just "clear"  the vector without a costly reallocation. Of couse, the performance of this procedure is highly dependent on the number of elements - this is just the easy way out.

Comment: I dont want to resize. The boundary conditions are: The vector should be cleared so that afterwards it can be filled again with `push_back` up to the same capacity. Sorry if this wasnt clear

Comment: Alright then. It seems i misunderstood it; sorry.